# window.top.document.body.scrollTop not working in Chrome or FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I have the code below that will open a modal window. This works in IE 8 but not in Chrome or FF. I am new to the world of cross browser functionality.

```
function ShowModal(WindowID,FramesetID)
{
    window.onscroll = function () { window.top.document.getElementById(WindowID).style.top = window.top.document.body.scrollTop; };
    window.top.document.getElementById(WindowID).style.display = "block";
    window.top.document.getElementById(WindowID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop;

    widthv=parseInt(parseInt(screen.width)/1.50);
    heightv=parseInt(parseInt(screen.height)/1.50); 

    window.top.document.getElementById(FramesetID).style.width=widthv;
    window.top.document.getElementById(FramesetID).style.height=heightv;
}
```

Can anyone help in making this code Chrome & FF compatible?
I tried changing `window.top` to `window.parent` but no luck
Also, any rules to keep in mind when coding for multiple browsers (I have browsed through but didn't quite find any set of rules for cross browser compatibility)?

**Update:**
The issue is that in IE, this modal window appears in approximately half the screensize. In FF and Chrome, the modal window appears about the size of a dollar coin.

Comment: have you considered using something like jquery to take the pain out of cross browser functionality?

Comment: @DotNetRookie: You would get more help if you could post the actual error messages.  Both Chrome and Firefox have a "JavaScript console" view that shows error and warning messages from JavaScript code.

Comment: @Daniel, there is not error message technically. The modal winodw appears significantly smaller than is designed to be (in FF and Chrome).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I'd recommend jQuery like chrispanda has suggested. jQuery has a built in scroll event and the rest can be written in just a few lines to manipulate the html / css.

http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 32):

Depending on your browser's current rendering mode, you may need to use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` instead of `document.body.scrollTop` (and likewise for `scrollLeft`).

There's some good background on this problem in [an Evolt article by Peter-Paul Koch](http://evolt.org/node/23335/) (of quirksmode.org fame), but it's from 2002 and is a bit dated now.

As others here are suggesting, the easiest way to solve this kind of problem in 2011 is to just use an existing JavaScript framework.  [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is quite popular (especially among StackOverflow users), but [there are many others as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks).

Comment: Is this still the case in 2017? It seems ridiculous that I should have to use a third party library for something so simple.

Comment: document.documentElement.scrollTop is working fine in modern browsers..

Answer (score 20):

Another solution:

```
(document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use:

window.pageYOffset

Comment: zsimo, Maybe you can elaborate what this does and where the OP can find reference on this. That would raise the quality of your answer.

Comment: sure:

I do not think it is necessary to use jQuery for the problem with Firefox the returns 0 with document.body.scrollTop

Simply use window.pageYOffset to get the distance from the top when the page scrolls:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollY

Simone

Comment: Worked for me. Chrome, IE9, Firefox. Thanks @zsimo!

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome, IE10, Firefox

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see the need for unecessary third party libraries, you could try:

```
var scrollTop = (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
```

It's hacky, but it's still better than JQuery.

Comment: This answer is WRONG. Surely you never tried this code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i checked my code for a set overflow, removing:

```
overflow:auto;
```

from another element worked

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to check every x milliseconds as a workaround. Not ideal, but it worked for me as I couldn't find any other solution. Note, this is ES6 code, so if you need to, you'll have to make it ES5 compatible manually, or use Babel.

```
/**
 * Set the scroll top on load
 * @param {int} scrollTop The scrollTop
 */
let setScrollTop = scrollTop => {
    // Different browsers treat this differently, so set all
    window.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    window.document.body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    window.document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
};

/**
 * Jump to a page
 * @param {string} selector
 */
let jumpToPage = selector => {
    let i = 0;
    let top = document.querySelector(selector).offsetTop;
    let interval;

    interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        if ((document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop) === top || i === 20) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }

        setScrollTop(top);

        i++;
    }, 100);

    setScrollTop(top);
};

/**
 * On load
 */
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (condition) {
        jumpToPage(selector);
    }
});
```