# Setting Page Scroll Cross-Browser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I've been working on a project for work where I need to create a Javascript "jump-menu" within a page.

(**Q**:Wait, a jump-menu? Why don't you just use `a` elements and namespaces to navigate within your page?

**A**: Because that would defeat the purpose! So please, don't provide answers like that. I need to do this with Javascript (AND I'M NOT USING JQUERY!!!))

So, here is what I do:

I make a list at the top of the page, and a list at the bottom of the page.

I add an event listener to each list item at the top of the page and I attach a reference to that list items corresponding content item within the page.

When the link at the top is clicked, I grab to `offsetTop` of the item I want to scroll to, and I set either the `document.body.scrollTop` or the `window.pageYOffset`.

I've never actually needed the `window.pageYOffset`, but somewhere told me it would work and I never removed it from my code. Either way, this appears to work with the `document.body.scrollTop` in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, yet it doesn't work in Firefox or IE. Why?

Here is the code block where I set the `document.body.scrollTop`:

```
if(elem.jump_ref)
{
    if(document.body.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop === 0)
    {
        document.body.scrollTop = elem.jump_ref.offsetTop - page_top_padding;
    }
    else if(window.pageYOffset || window.pageYOffset === 0)
    {
        window.pageYOffset = elem.jump_ref.offsetTop - page_top_padding;
    }
}
```

[**And Heres The Project In JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/t2a3o5f9/)

I've stepped through and found that "Yes, I am grabbing the right element." and "Yes, I am setting the `document.body.scrollTop`, and "No, I am not setting the `document.body.scrollTop` to zero." and yet it still doesn't work! Please help! My webpage is supposed to go public on Tuesday!

Comment: You shouldn't be so salty while asking for help...

Comment: Your post is duplicated... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435843/window-top-document-body-scrolltop-not-working-in-chrome-or-firefox

Comment: What? @PedroMoreira Maybe you mis-interpreted my mood through text, but I'm really not sure how I was being "salty." Sorry...

Comment: And yes @PedroMoreira , the link you provided does appear to be the same exact topic as mine. Sorry, I did not find this post before I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe I have found my answer. So far, it appears to work in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, and Safari (these were the only ones I was able to test). I don't know what type of mobile support this feature will have (if any), but my page already has an entirely different functionality for mobile anyway.

Either way, here's the fix. Its the `window.scrollTo` method!:

```
this.jump = function(evt)
{
    var elem = evt.srcElement || evt.currentTarget;
    var page_top_padding = 100;

    if(elem.jump_ref)
    {
        window.scrollTo(0, (elem.post_ref.offsetTop - page_top_padding));
    }
}.bind(this);
```

And like I said, it works great in nearly everything! Everything except JSFiddle. lol. I don't quite get it, but luckily no one is going to be visiting my webpage in JSFiddle.